# R networkD3 change node IMG

Tags: r, networkd3

I would like to replace the basic node image to a custom jpg in networkD3 package in R.

Here is an example:

```
library(networkD3)

# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
            Source = "source", Target = "target",
            Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
            Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

So I would like to create a node like this:
[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: For me it is also good with any other interacive R network package...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to **replace the basic node image** to a custom jpg in
>   networkD3 package in R. [...] For me it is also good with any other
>   **interacive R network package**

For example, you could do

```
library(networkD3)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)
visNetwork(
  MisNodes %>% 
    rename("label"=name) %>% 
    mutate(id = seq_len(nrow(MisNodes))-1),
  MisLinks %>% 
    rename("from"=source, "to"=target)
) %>%
  visNodes(
    shape = "image", 
    image = "http://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/mark-github-128.png"
  )
```

giving you

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is works!
Is it not possible with networkD3 BTW?

Comment: I dunno. Have you looked at the documentation?